# Разность значений по соседнему столбцу

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, как можно реализовать запрос?

Необходимо, чтобы БД посчитала разность в зависимости от соседнего столбца.

Пример:

```
select (sum(q1) and q2 = 18) - (sum(q1) and q2 = 2) 
from t1
```

Значение из 1 строки вычесть значение 2 строки, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: См. функции LEAD/LAG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не совсем ясен вопрос. на рисунке у вас просто две строки которые вы хотите вычесть. В тексте вы пишите про сумму, что подразумевает, что у вас много строк с q2=18 и их надо просуммировать.

в первом случае можете использовать подзапросы

```
 SELECT 
     (select q1 from t where q2 = 18)
   - (select q1 from t where q2 = 2) AS res
```

в случае множества строк и суммирования добавляете `case`, и получаете наподобие

```
SELECT
    SUM(case when q2 = 18 then q1 else 0 end)
  - SUM(case when q2 = 2 then q1 else 0 end) as res
FROM t
```